# Find the added volume of HCl so that the ions separate

Tags: equilibrium, aqueous-solution, solubility, stoichiometry, salt

> Suppose we have a 10mL solution that contains 0.02M $\ce{Ag^+}$ and 0.04M $\ce{Ba^{2+}}$. a) Find the necessary volume to be added of $\ce{HCl}$ to separate all the silver. (**Assume to be separated if there is less than 0'1% of remaining silver in the solution of what it was initially**)

So here I tried to do it using the constant of solubility that is given to be $Ks(AgCl)=1.8*10^{-10}$ noting that that new concentration of silver has to be 0'1% of the initial one, which means to me $[Ag^+]'=\frac{0.1}{100}[Ag^+]_0$ hence using the constant: $$Ks(AgCl)=[Ag^+]'[Cl^-]'=[Ag^+]'(s+c_{\text{added}})$$ because we have added some quantity to the solubility of $\ce{Cl-}$, and then since the constant is of the order of $10^{-10}$ we can approximate to $s\approx 0$: $$Ks(AgCl)=0.001[Ag^+]_0\cdot c_{\text{added}}\implies c_{\text{added}}=\frac{Ks(AgCl)}{0.001[Ag^+]_0}$$ but I don't think that's right since I don't get the answer that my books suggests.

Comment: You have found how much Cl- should stay in the solution to achieve the desired result. That's not what the problem asks, though. It asks how much Cl- **should be added**, and not all of that Cl- would stay in the solution. Some would go down with AgCl.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin But the thing is that I don't know how I would do that

Comment: is concentration of HCl given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an equilibrium shift problem in which adding $\ce{HCl}$ produces two different effects simultaneously:

(1) Change in total volume of solution.

(2) Change in moles of $\ce{Cl-}$ ions present in solution.

We'll start by defining equations for the equilibrium number of moles of each relevant species in the equilibrium system:

$$\ce{AgCl(s) <=> Ag+(aq) + Cl-(aq)}$$

Let:

$S$ represent $\ce{Ag+}$

$C$ represent $\ce{Cl-}$

$A$ represent $\ce{HCl}$

At equilibrium, (after HCl is added) the moles of silver and chloride ions are, respectively:

$$N_{\ce{S}}=N_{So}-x$$

$$N_{\ce{C}}=N_{Co}-x$$

We're told that at desired separation:

$$N_S=0.001\;N_{So}$$

Substituting above and solving for x:

$$0.001\; N_{So}=N_{So}-x\;\;\implies\;\; x=0.999\;N_{So}$$

Substituting in $N_C$:

$$N_C=N_{Co}-0.999\;N_{So}$$

We then use the relationship between $K_N$ and $K_{sp}$ to form this expression:

$$K_{N}=K_{sp}\;(V_S+V_A)^2=N_S\;N_C=(0.001\;N_{So})(N_{Co}-0.999\;N_{So})$$

Where $V_S$ is the volume of the solution before $\ce{HCl}$ is added, and $V_A$ is the volume of $\ce{HCl}$ added.

Since $\ce{HCl}$ is a strong acid, we can assume that it's dissociated completely and:

$$N_{Ao}=N_{Co}$$

$$V_A=\frac{N_{Ao}}{C_{Ao}}$$

So, we have:

$$\left(\frac{N_{Ao}}{C_{Ao}}+V_S\right)^2=\frac{(0.001\;N_{So})(N_{Ao}-0.999\;N_{So})}{K_{sp}}$$

Plugging in all the known values we're given:

$N_{So}=2*10^{-4}\;mol$

$K_{sp}=1.8*10^{-10}$

$V_S=0.01\;L$

$$\left(\frac{N_{Ao}}{C_{Ao}}+0.01\right)^2=\frac{(2\times10^{-7})(N_{Ao}-1.998\times10^{-4})}{1.8\times10^{-10}}$$

It's important to note that the volume of $\ce{HCl}$ required depends on how concentrated it is, so $C_{Ao}$ should be given.

For example, if we have $\ce{HCl}$ 0.01$\;$M, then we would get when solving for $N_{Ao}$:

$$N_{Ao}=2.006\times10^{-4}\;mol$$

And finally:

$$V_A=\frac{N_{Ao}}{C_{Ao}}=\frac{2.006\times10^{-4}\;mol}{0.01\;mol/L}=0.02006\;L=20.06\;mL$$

If you would like to observe how $V_A$ varies as a function of $C_{Ao}$, you can plot:

$$V_A=\frac{2000\;C_{Ao}-0.036\;-\sqrt{\left(0.036-2000\;C_{Ao}\right)^2-2.878416}}{3.6}$$

Note that $C_{Ao}$ is in mol/L, and resulting $V_A$ value will be in liters (L).

A plot of $V_A$ (mL) vs $C_{Ao}$ (mol/L) from 0.01M to 0.1M, would look like this:

[image]

Comment: I've noticed that you've written quite a few MathJax heavy posts recently. Please look into the mhchem package, it'll make typesetting easier and it'll produce proper typesetting. There is more information on our meta site.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Thank you. I will look it up.

Answer (score 1):

BaCl2 is water soluble.  AgCl is not.  Adding HCl to the solution of 0.02M Ag+ and 0.04M Ba+ will produce an AgCl precipitate.

There are 10 ml of original solution.

10 ml × 0.02 mmol/ml Ag+ = 0.20 mmol (millimoles) Ag+

Therefor 0.20 millimoles HCl should be added to get **at least** 99.9% separation of AgCl.

Interestingly, with AgCl, adding *excess* chloride will actually increase the solubility of AgCl, so care must be taken to not exceed the proper amount.

1.0 ml of 0.2 M HCl will drop most of the silver as AgCl ppt.

Comment: mM is not the proper way to write millimole; most chemists will read it as millimolar, which is mmol/L, and there you also see the proper symbol for millimole: mmol.